# Rasa-SDK: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, rasa, rasa-sdk

After create build my Dockerfile

```
# server.Dockerfile
FROM rasa/rasa-sdk:3.6.2

USER root

COPY ./actions ./app/actions

RUN apt-get update

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir requests

USER 1001
```

This error was launched in Docker Desktop after run `docker run -d -v ${PWD}/actions:/app/actions --net rasa-action-network --name action_server rasa/rasa-sdk:3.6.2`

```
2024-01-22 14:18:00 /opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sanic_cors/extension.py:39: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
2024-01-22 14:18:00   SANIC_VERSION = LooseVersion(sanic_version)
2024-01-22 14:18:00 2024-01-22 20:18:00 INFO     rasa_sdk.endpoint  - Starting action endpoint server...
2024-01-22 14:18:00 2024-01-22 20:18:00 ERROR    rasa_sdk.executor  - Failed to register package 'actions'.
2024-01-22 14:18:00 Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-01-22 14:18:00   File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rasa_sdk/executor.py", line 263, in register_package
2024-01-22 14:18:00     self._import_submodules(package)
2024-01-22 14:18:00   File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rasa_sdk/executor.py", line 226, in _import_submodules
2024-01-22 14:18:00     self._import_module(full_name)
2024-01-22 14:18:00   File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rasa_sdk/executor.py", line 240, in _import_module
2024-01-22 14:18:00     module = importlib.import_module(name)
2024-01-22 14:18:00   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2024-01-22 14:18:00     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2024-01-22 14:18:00   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
2024-01-22 14:18:00   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
2024-01-22 14:18:00   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2024-01-22 14:18:00   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
2024-01-22 14:18:00   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
2024-01-22 14:18:00   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
2024-01-22 14:18:00   File "/app/actions/actions.py", line 11, in <module>
2024-01-22 14:18:00     import requests
2024-01-22 14:18:00 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Inside `actions.py` there is the start of the file

[image: snippet of the code]

Someone have idea in how to install `requests` in `rasa-sdk` in the `Dockerfile` or as a parameter in `compose` command?

If you need more information, please let me know to share with you.

Answer (score 0):

I have tweaked your `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM rasa/rasa-sdk:3.6.2

USER root

RUN apt-get update && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir requests

COPY ./actions /app/actions

USER 1001
```

Changes:

1. Move `COPY` to end so that image builds quickly when you make code changes.
2. Change the target for `COPY` to an absolute path.
3. Consolidate the two `RUN` commands.

In `actions/actions.py`:

```
import requests

print("Hello!")
```

Build and run.

```bash
docker build -t rasa .
docker run -it rasa
```

Output:

```
2024-01-23 05:10:29 INFO rasa_sdk.endpoint  - Starting action endpoint server...
Hello!
2024-01-23 05:10:29 INFO rasa_sdk.endpoint  - Starting plugins...
2024-01-23 05:10:29 INFO rasa_sdk.endpoint  - Action endpoint is up and running on http://0.0.0.0:5055
```

The `docker run` command in your question appears to run the base image (`rasa/rasa-sdk:3.6.2`) rather than your derived image.